# Dynamic Java Script Table Border not sizing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

You can see the site here: [Memory Game](http://castro.kr0w.com/)
(not sure why cards are spaced out.. want them to be close together)

I'm trying to create a simple site that creates a table of images for memory card game. Images load correctly, and the Java Script seems to work, but I can't seem to get the border to dynamically size with the size of the table. No matter what I do, the border width expands across the whole screen irregardless that the images that make up the table are much smaller than the area the border encompasses. (Ironically, the height seems to dynamically change correctly, but not the width.) Many thanks in advance!

Here is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src = "tableGen.js"></script> 
</head>
<body onload = "startTable('easy')">

        <div id="masthead">
            <img src="Images/GreyKnight.jpg" width = "450" height="200" alt="40k Table Top">
            <img src="Images/WarhammerLogo.png" width = "450" height="200" alt="Warhammer40K Logo">
            <img src="Images/SpaceMarine.jpg" width = "450" height="200" alt="Space Marine">
            <h1>
                Warhammer 40K Memory Card Game 
            </h1>
        </div>
        <br>

    <div id = "tableDiv">
            This text should be removed by the javascript. 
    </div>


    <form name = "input" >
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="easy" checked = "checked" onClick ="startTable('easy')">Easy<br>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="medium" onClick ="startTable('medium')">Medium<br>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="hard" onClick ="startTable('hard')">Hard<br>   
    </form>

    </body> 


    </html>

here is the Java Script 

    function startTable(setting) {
    "use strict";

    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("tableDiv"); 
    var checkSetting = setting; 
    var newVar; 
    tableDiv.innerHTML = genTable(setting); 
    }

    function genTable(setting)
    {
"use strict"; 
var html = ""; 
var i = 0; 

if(setting == "easy")
    i = 4; 
else if(setting == "medium")
    i = 6; 
else if(setting == "hard") 
    i = 8; 

html += "<table> "; 
for (var col = i; col > 0; col--)
{
html += "<tr>"; 
for (var row = i; row > 0; row--)
{
 html += "<td><img src=\"Images/Cards/Card_Back.jpg\" width = \"80\" height=\"121\" alt=\"Card       Back\"></td>"
}
}
html += "</table>";

return html;
```

Here is the CSS

```
 body {
margin: 5px;
background-color: black;
color: white;  
font-family: Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif; 
text-align: left;

}

h1 { text-align: center; 
font-family:Georgia, serif;
color: red;
}

h2 { text-align: left; 
font-size: 22px; 
color: red;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

}


table
{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr td {
    padding: 5px; 
}

table tr td img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
img {
outline: 4px solid #eee;
}

a:link {
    color: #22F01B;
}

a:visited {
    color: yellow;
}


#masthead {
    text-align:center; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    border-bottom-style:dashed; 
    border-bottom-width:medium;
    border-bottom-color:#000080;  
}


#tableDiv{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
   }
```

Comment: Do you mean the border of images you generated dynamically? and do you want to remove those image borders?

Comment: @DotnetLearners What i'm referring to is the white border that goes around the table itself. The border around the images themselves is fine, but the table border is where I'm having the border sizing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the CSS like below, it will align the cards with equal spacings.

```
table tr td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

There is actually three versions of the game which are easy, medium and hard.
So you can dynamically change the table width based on the type of game selected via java script.

For ex: for easy mode, you can update #tableDiv width to for 960px and similarly different widths for different modes of game as the table grows.

```
#tableDiv {
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0 0;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all the javascript code should be in between tags .
if still it doesnt work please try to use Jquery library it would this work more easy

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS

```
#tableDiv {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}
table {
    /* width: 100%; */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```